# What is the name of third-gender avatar of Hari?

Tags: scripture, vishnu, avatars, gender

Garuda Purana tells that Vishnu will born to kill an asura. Vishnu takes the form of an eunuch

> The gods would be divided into different clans such as the
> Svadharmans, Sutapasas, Haritas, Rohitas, etc., and Rtadhama or Bhadra
> would be their Indra or overlord. The demon Taraka would invade the
> territories of the then lord of the celestials. **O Sankara, the god
> Hari, incarnate as a eunuch**, would destroy that fell perace-breaker of
> the universe.
>
> [[53, Chapter 87: Fourteen Manus, Garuda Puranam]](https://archive.org/details/GarudaPuranamSanskritEnglish/page/n229/mode/2up)

Do any scripture tells the name of the avatar mentioned?

Comment: The passage says the eunuch avatara will take place when the demon Taraka invades. Is demon Taraka the same as Tarakasura?

Comment: I'm thinking as the same. But not sure. @Rickross

Comment: @Rickross There are many asuras called Taraka. It seems to be a common asura name.. The famous one is the son of Vajranga  https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/vishnu-purana-wilson/d/doc115957.html https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226078.html